# How to get minimum number of occurrences of value in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
          home_team_name  home_team_goal_count
0         Bayern München                     2
1         Bayern München                     2
2         Bayern München                     1
3                   Köln                     2
4                   Köln                     2
```

I groupby the data on the variable home_team_name.

```
df.groupby("home_team_name")
```

The values of `home_team_goal_count` can only be 2 or 1. I want to get the minimum number of occurrences
of the values in each group. The result I would want is 1 for Bayern Munchen and 0 for Koln. To illustrate Bayern Munchen has 2 times 2 and 1 times 1, therefore the minimum is 1. Koln has 2 times 2 and 0 time 1 therefore the minimum is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First count values by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html), reshape and add `0` for all combinations `1,2` and last get minimum by `min`:

```
s = (df.groupby("home_team_name")['home_team_goal_count']
       .value_counts()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .min(axis=1))

print (s)
home_team_name
Bayern München    1
Köln              0
dtype: int64
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby("home_team_name")['home_team_goal_count']
         .value_counts()
         .unstack(fill_value=0))
home_team_goal_count  1  2
home_team_name            
Bayern München        1  2
Köln                  0  2
```

If possible only `1` or only `2` values in input data is necessary `reindex`:

```
s = (df.groupby("home_team_name")['home_team_goal_count']
       .value_counts()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .reindex([1, 2], axis=1, fill_value=0) 
       .min(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try using [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['home_team_name'], df['home_team_goal_count'])\
    .reindex([1, 2], axis=1, fill_value=0).min(1)
```

Result:

```
home_team_name
Bayern München    1
Köln              0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
list1=['Bayern Munchen','Bayern Munchen','Bayern Munchen','FC Koln','FC Koln']
list2=[2,2,1,2,2]
d={'Home Team Name':list1,'Home Team Goal Count':list2}
data=pd.DataFrame(d)

data['Name']= data['Home Team Name'] +" "+ data['Home Team Goal Count'].astype(str)

data['Name']
Out[39]: 
0    Bayern Munchen 2
1    Bayern Munchen 2
2    Bayern Munchen 1
3           FC Koln 2
4           FC Koln 2

name,count=np.unique(data['Name'].tolist(),return_counts=True)

name=[' '.join(x.split(' ')[:-1]) for x in name]

name
Out[99]: ['Bayern Munchen', 'Bayern Munchen', 'FC Koln']

min_val=pd.DataFrame({"Name":name,"Count":count})

name=[]
min_val_count=[]
for x in min_val.Name.unique():
    name.append(min_val[min_val.Name!=x].min()[0])
if min_val[min_val.Name!=x].min()[1]==2:
    min_val_count.append(0)
else:
    min_val_count.append(min_val[min_val.Name!=x].min()[1])


minimum_val_dict=dict(zip(name,min_val_count))

minimum_val_dict
Out[104]: {'FC Koln': 0, 'Bayern Munchen': 1}
```

A slightly longer version as compared to the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Even another way to do this would be to use a cateorical variable, since there's a finite set of states. So:

```
(
    df
    .astype({"home_team_goal_count": "category"})
    .groupby("home_team_name")["home_team_goal_count"]
    .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().min())
)
```

If you want to know which value occurred the least, you can call `.idxmin()` instead of `.min()`.